# Handling missing values in pandas dataframe as input for tensorflow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, data-analysis

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    ID    Age    Sex    Loc
1   1     33     F      S
2   2     64     M      C
3   3     49     M      C
4   4            M      S
5   5     31     F      U
```

There are other columns but this is enough for the question. I use this as input for a neural network. My problem is the missing age values. Other columns have all their data, but there are about 5% missing age values across the entire dataset (train and test). I can easily just skip those rows but that causes problems later when I want to relate the ID number from the test set to the prediction as the indexes don't match up any more. So how do I clean up that column in a way that it can still run through the NN without screwing up my results? Should I just assume the mean of the total set for all empties?

With just skipping the rows as I loop through and convert M/F to 1/0 and the Loc to 0/1/2 worked. My network get 81% accurate. I'm just wondering if finding a way to leave those rows in would make it more accurate, and as I delve deeper this seems like something that will come up often in real world data.

Assume I'm an idiot when it comes to python, but have 21 years of webdev experience in javascript/angular/databases/etc. ;) Thanks for any suggestions on this one.

Comment: i think its very much upto you and your accuracy, normally if i had a very large data set and only 5% data is missing i would happily skip those, but most commonly fill these values with mean/median/mode depending on skewness.

Comment: @M_S_N This particular dataset isn't huge. 5% probably isn't going to make a big impact, but it got me thinking that I didn't really know how to handle this. That makes sense with the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no one current answer here, you basiclly have to try and see what works.

**Method 1:**
Like you suggested, you can remove all the rows with a missing value.

```
df.dropna(axis=0)
```

**Method 2:**
Fill them with constant value, for example, 0.

```
 df.fillna(0)
```

**Method 3:**
Fill them with the median or mean column value

```
df.fillna(df.mean())
```

Comment: Agree. It depends on the amount of missing values, domain knowledge, and data generation process.

Comment: Missing about 5% of the values in that column, so it's not a ton, but it got me thinking. I wondered about using the mean as well or if there was some sort of best practice. Seems the best practice is whatever makes the model most accurate, which makes sense. It just felt wrong dropping the values entirely. Good advice and I'm going to fiddle around with these and see what I get.

Comment: You can use the MICE package from the R language. It works pretty well.